# Align all icon to the right of page regardless of start point React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to be able to align all reply icons to the far right, where the red line is, regardless of where they start.

[image]

**Edit**: added more information to show how recursion is used in the component. Why I try to use some answers that work without recursion, I receive an undesired effect.

This is the code I have in place so far:

```
class Comment extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Header
                    rounded
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                        position: 'relative',
                    }}
                >
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', right: '43%', top: '50%'}}>
                        <Icon name='chevron-left' size={10} color='#006FFF' style={{top: '6%'}}/>
                        <NativeText
                            onPress={() => this.props.history.push('/')}
                            style ={{color: '#006FFF', fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular'}}
                        >
                            Back
                        </NativeText>
                    </View>
                </Header>
                <View
                    style={{paddingLeft: '2%', paddingTop: '2%'}}
                >
                    <CommentList

                        options={this.props.location.state.comments}
                        currentUser={this.props.location.state.currentUser}
                        history={this.props.history}
                        reportId={this.props.location.state.reportId}
                        optionsForBackButton={this.props.location.state.comments}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Comment)

const CommentList = ({options, currentUser, history, reportId, optionsForBackButton}) => {

    return ( 
      <View>
          {options.map(option => (
              <View
                style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}
              >
                <NativeText
                    style={{fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular'}}
                >
                    {option.content}
                </NativeText>
                <View
                     style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}
                >
                    <Icon

                        name='reply'
                        size={12}
                        // onPress={() => {
                        //     setModalVisible(true)
                        //     changeParentId(option._id)
                        // }}
                        onPress={() => history.push({pathname: '/create-comment', state: {content: option.content, currentUser: currentUser, reportId: reportId, parentCommentId: option._id, optionsForBackButton: optionsForBackButton}})}
                    />
                </View>
                { 
                <View
                    style={{left: '10%'}}
                >
                    <CommentList
                        options={option.reply}
                        optionsForBackButton={optionsForBackButton}
                        history={history}
                        currentUser={currentUser}
                        reportId={reportId}
                    />
                </View>
                }
            </View>
          ))}
      </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: i have an idea. you can try adding the outer `<View />` enclosing the content and the icon with `... flexDirection: 'row'` and the `<View />` enclosing only the icon with `... position: 'absolute', right: 20, alignItems: 'flex-end'`.

Answer (score 0):

Set your icon containing view's flex value to 1. This should cause it to fill all remaining space.

See the following snack: https://snack.expo.io/@jrdndncn/playful-churros

```js
class Comment extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          marginVertical: 2,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          marginLeft: (this.props.indent || 0) * 20,
        }}>
        <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
          <View style={{ width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

<Comment text="hello" indent={0} />
<Comment text="hello" indent={1} />
<Comment text="hello" indent={2} />
```

Comment: In my effort to reduce the amount of code in my post, I left out the recursive aspect. I made an edit to show what the full component looks like. When I tried your solution, I gave me an undesired result  and moved the replies off page.

Answer (score 0):

Basically marginLeft:'auto' will do the trick. just add style to icon as :

```
                <Icon

                    name='reply'
                    size={12}
                    style={{marginLeft:'auto'}}
                    // onPress={() => {
                    //     setModalVisible(true)
                    //     changeParentId(option._id)
                    // }}
                    onPress={() => history.push({pathname: '/create-comment', state: {content: option.content, currentUser: currentUser, reportId: reportId, parentCommentId: option._id, optionsForBackButton: optionsForBackButton}})}
                />
```

i added marginLeft:'auto' in style it will automatically shown at the right end of the screen.

Comment: I pushed most of the icons off the screen

Comment: can you provide expo link for your code. I think problem is with flex then